# Disable google ads after a visitor made a purchase, using cookie or javascript

Tags: cookies, google-ads-api

I have an ecommerce site where user will click on an ad served by google to make a purchase. Due to the nature of our business, we do not have repeat customers (<1% return business). We offer an option to track the progress of their custom orders on our website.

The problem is that many customer who bought the product click on the google ad to get to our site in order to use the tracking. All these clicks cost money but do not generate revenues.

I am hoping to run a piece of code, or set a cookie after a user make a purchase so that my ad is not displayed in the google search. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep sure this is totally possible

1. Create a new remarketing tag in AdWords (shared Library > Audiences > + Remarketing List) - call it something like "Purchasers".
2. Take the new tag and place it only on your purchase complete/thanks/confirmation page.  This means that you are creating a new audience list of people who have purchased because only people who got to the purchase complete page will load the tag.
3. Back in AdWords, go to your search campaign and click on the Audiences tab (Audiences is only visible if the campaign is set to use "All Features" in the campaign type settings).
4. At the bottom of the page click "+Exclusions"
5. Enter your ad group(s)
6. Under Campaign Exclusions, click "Add campaign exclusions" and select "Interests & Remarketing"
7. Select the remarketing list you created in step 1 and click Close
8. Click Save and you're done - you'll now not show ads to people who have already purchased.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are already running remarketing campaign then you need not to add a new remarketing tag in your complete/thanks/confirmation page (your all pages must have remarketing tag). You just need to create a new remarketing list by selecting your complete/thanks/confirmation page and add this list in +Exclusions.

Adwords will stop showing your ads to the visitors who visited complete/thanks/confirmation page.